# How do I get a dirt block with sharpness enchantment level 300 In Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I do this? What command do I use to get an item with sharpness 300?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! In future, it is good practice to add any effort you have made already to the question. For example, you can add your attempted command(s) to show the effort you have made up to this point. You can also add what you're trying to achieve with this (just a brief explanation) like "I want to use it as a weapon" or "I am trying to create a trap". This can help us give you the answer you're after.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 2):

Just use this command:

```
/give @p dirt{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:300}]} 1
```

Not sure why you want a dirt block with sharpness 300. Not gonna question it.